# Why is Windows 11 Numlock flickering

Tags: windows, keyboard

Suddenly on my Gigabyte G5 MD Windows 11 laptop NumLock started constantly to turn itself on and off,
please any ideas is it a hardware or OS issue?

Comment: I'd see if its happening in BIOS or boot menu. If it is then yeah its hardware, likely a flaky key. Otherwise software could be causing

Comment: bios and boot menu were working normally, it was reproduced in safe windows mode, key seemed to work properly and switched Numlock mode when pressed, and finally after Windows update it've got back to normal, hope I won't face it again

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your NumLock key has gotten stuck. Look for dirt around the edges of the key and see if there's anything that might be affecting the key's motion.

Edit: You may have to pop the key cap off and look for stuff under the key. Usually they can be popped off and snapped back on, but that does vary from one keyboard to another; since I don't have a Gigabyte G5 MD laptop, I can't be absolutely certain how easy that will be to do.

Answer (score 0):

do you have Windows Hello activates? if so, try to turn it off and check if it was fixes, and also you can try to turn off the option "Automatically dismiss the lock screen if Windows recognizes your face".

i hope this helps.

Comment: this question needs support information to explain it